# How to Programmatically collect GC statistics?

Tags: java, android

In android, how do you obtain GC stats Programmatically?

To better understand my app's startup latency, one of the stats I need to collect is the amount of time spent in GC.  I should add, I am using java.

Comment: So you want to measure your app on the users's devices or is it just for you? Have you tried the [Android Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler) of Android Studio?

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear: on the actual end user devices.  We cannot use profilers or systrace.